# RawKeyboardListener not fired any event in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, keyboard, widget, listener

Here it is simple code inside some widget. The `RawKeyboardListener`'s `onKey` is not triggered! So the question why? Is it a bug?

```dart
Container(
  child: StreamProvider<Item>.value(
    value: stream
    child: Consumer<Item>(
      builder: (_, item, __) {
        return RawKeyboardListener(
          focusNode: focusNode,
          onKey: (event) {
            print(event); // NOT PRINTED!!
          }
          child: TextField(
            controller: controller,
            ...
          ),
        );
      }
    ),
  ),
),
```

P.S. Flutter is `1.17.0-3.2pre`, Dart is `2.8.0-dev.20.10`

Comment: Got the very same problem. Did you solve it? It seems to work perfectly well in the debug version and then fails to function in the release app. Frustrating...

Comment: I have the same issue, works in debug, profile but not in release build for web.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to add this line to the top of your builder method:

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
```

Your code should look like this:

```
Container(
  child: StreamProvider<Item>.value(
    value: stream
    child: Consumer<Item>(
      builder: (_, item, __) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode); // Add this line

        return RawKeyboardListener(
          focusNode: focusNode,
          onKey: (event) {
            print(event); // NOT PRINTED!!
          }
          child: TextField(
            controller: controller,
            ...
          ),
        );
      }
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work for me. It works fine in the debug app and then fails in the release app.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured out why keys (and `Enter` especially) are not catched by `RawKeyboardListener`. It is required to add `onChange` callback (for catching keyboard events) and an empty `onEditingComplete` callback (for catching `Enter` key).

```dart
RawKeyboardListener(
  focusNode: focusNode,
  onKey: (event) {
    if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
      print('enter key pressed'); // <--- works!
    } else {
      print('key ${event.logicalKey} pressed');
    }
  }
  child: TextField(
    controller: controller,
    onChange: (value) { /* handle text change*/}
    onEditingComplete: () { /* this is required to catch Enter key */ }
  ),
)
```